# Error on FOSUserBundle, argument passed must be an instance of ObjectManager

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I've seen all the posts about this subject but nothing has helped me. I think my problem is slightly different. I use FOSUser bundle on a Symfony 4 project. When I access my website I get this error:

```
Argument 3 passed to FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager, instance of ContainerVxxTSSB\EntityManager_9a5be93 given, called in C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Dev\project\var\cache\dev\ContainerVxxTSSB\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php on line 1885
```

I don't know where the error is from, since it indicates a file in the cache. I tried deleting the var folder, but still the same error. The thing that I don't understand is that the error says that I give an instance of "ContainerVxxTSSB\EntityManager_9a5be93" but I don't see how it could be possible.
I don't even know where to search to resolve this.

services.yaml

```
  user_factory:
        class: App\Security\UserFactory
        arguments: ["@fos_user.user_manager", "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "%kernel.logs_dir%"]
```

UserFactory.php:

```
use App\Entity\User;
use FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager;
use Hslavich\OneloginSamlBundle\Security\Authentication\Token\SamlTokenInterface;
use Hslavich\OneloginSamlBundle\Security\User\SamlUserFactoryInterface;



class UserFactory implements SamlUserFactoryInterface
{
    private $userManager;
    private $entityManager;
    private $logs_dir;

    public function __construct(UserManager $userManager, $entityManager, $logs_dir)
    {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->logs_dir = $logs_dir;
    }
```

and then in UserManager.php in the vendor folder:

```
/**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param PasswordUpdaterInterface $passwordUpdater
     * @param CanonicalFieldsUpdater   $canonicalFieldsUpdater
     * @param ObjectManager            $om
     * @param string                   $class
     */
    public function __construct(PasswordUpdaterInterface $passwordUpdater, CanonicalFieldsUpdater $canonicalFieldsUpdater, ObjectManager $om, $class)
    {
        parent::__construct($passwordUpdater, $canonicalFieldsUpdater);

        $this->objectManager = $om;
        $this->class = $class;
    }
```

Edit:
The doctrine info in the composer.json

```
"doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.8",
```

The line indicated by the error:

```
 return $this->services['fos_user.user_manager'] = new \FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager(($this->privates['fos_user.util.password_updater'] ?? $this->getFosUser_Util_PasswordUpdaterService()), ($this->privates['fos_user.util.canonical_fields_updater'] ?? $this->getFosUser_Util_CanonicalFieldsUpdaterService()), ($this->services['doctrine'] ?? $this->getDoctrineService())->getManager(NULL), 'App\\Entity\\User');
```

To create the project I did:

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton:"^4.4" project_name
```

And then to add the bundle

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle
```

I don't remember getting an error

EDIT 2:
When I want to clear cache with this command:

```
php bin/console clear:cache
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError {#742
  #message: "Argument 3 passed to FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager, instance of ContainerXNABQPE\EntityManager_9a5be93 given, called in C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Dev\test\var\cache\dev\ContainerXNABQPE\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php on line 1416"
  #code: 0
  #file: "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Dev\test\vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\Doctrine\UserManager.php"
  #line: 41
  trace: {
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Dev\test\vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\Doctrine\UserManager.php:41 { …}
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Dev\test\var\cache\dev\ContainerXNABQPE\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php:1416 {
      ContainerXNABQPE\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer->getFosUser_UserManagerService()
      ›
      ›     return $this->services['fos_user.user_manager'] = new \FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager(($this->privates['fos_user.util.password_updater'] ?? $this->getFosUser_Util_PasswordUpdaterService()), ($this->privates['fos_use
r.util.canonical_fields_updater'] ?? $this->getFosUser_Util_CanonicalFieldsUpdaterService()), ($this->services['doctrine'] ?? $this->getDoctrineService())->getManager(NULL), 'App\\Entity\\User');
      › }
      arguments: {
        $passwordUpdater: FOS\UserBundle\Util\PasswordUpdater {#739 …}
        $canonicalFieldsUpdater: FOS\UserBundle\Util\CanonicalFieldsUpdater {#741 …}
        $om: ContainerXNABQPE\EntityManager_9a5be93 {#647 …}
        $class: "App\Entity\User"
      }
    }
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Dev\test\var\cache\dev\ContainerXNABQPE\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php:4625 { …}
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Dev\test\var\cache\dev\ContainerXNABQPE\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php:4388 { …}
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Dev\test\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\Container.php:450 { …}
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Dev\test\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\Argument\ServiceLocator.php:40 { …}
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Dev\test\vendor\symfony\console\CommandLoader\ContainerCommandLoader.php:45 { …}
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Dev\test\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:548 { …}
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Dev\test\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:750 { …}
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Dev\test\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Console\Application.php:143 { …}
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Dev\test\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:561 { …}
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Dev\test\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:587 { …}
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Dev\test\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:657 { …}
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Dev\test\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Console\Application.php:117 { …}
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Dev\test\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:237 { …}
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Dev\test\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Console\Application.php:83 { …}
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Dev\test\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:149 { …}
    C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Dev\test\bin\console:42 { …}
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  Normally this would be a 'clear the cache' type issue but you already tried that.  You might try looking at srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php on line 1885.  It's basically where the UserFactory is created but I don't think it will help much.  Did you have this working before under 4.0?  I ask because the FOSUserBundle is not always maintained as well as perhaps it should be.  Could try creating a fresh 4.4 project, installing the FOSUserBundle and then comparing versions to see if there is some sort of mismatch.

Comment: The line where the error is "        return $this->services['fos_user.user_manager'] = new \FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager(($this->privates['fos_user.util.password_updater'] ?? $this->getFosUser_Util_PasswordUpdaterService()), ($this->privates['fos_user.util.canonical_fields_updater'] ?? $this->getFosUser_Util_CanonicalFieldsUpdaterService()), ($this->services['doctrine'] ?? $this->getDoctrineService())->getManager(NULL), 'App\\Entity\\User');
". This is a new project with Symfony 4.4, this is a fresh project from yesterday and I got this arror right away.

Comment: Consider updating your question with the above code.  Comments don't format well.  Though it does not seem like is mentions the logger directory anywhere.

Comment: Yes sorry, it's done

Comment: One more minor request.  I used 'composer new --full --version=lts project_name" followed by 'composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle' and composer complains about the twig version.  Consider updating your question with the commands you used to create your new project and to install the user bundle.

Comment: I could try doing a fresh project again, how should I start?

Comment: I get twig version errors.  Not sure why you don't.  In any event, FOSUserBundle is essentially abandoned. Probably be best to move onto something else unless you need to support legacy code. https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/2996

Comment: I do need to support legacy code with FOSUser and FOSComment.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response, I'm not sure whether you still need assistance but this should help you out. FOSUserBundle has clearly been pushed to it's end of life since there is no activity on the reposity. It is advisable to move away from it in the long-run. However, you can still make it work.

You will need to downgrade your `doctrine/orm` dependency version from `^2.8` to `2.7`.

Anything above `2.8` will require `doctrine/common` version `^3.0` which will cause you the problems you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

can you try the following:

```
use App\Entity\User;
use FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager;
use Hslavich\OneloginSamlBundle\Security\Authentication\Token\SamlTokenInterface;
use Hslavich\OneloginSamlBundle\Security\User\SamlUserFactoryInterface;



class UserFactory implements SamlUserFactoryInterface
{
    private $userManager;
    private $entityManager;
    private $logs_dir;

    public function __construct(UserManager $userManager, Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager $entityManager, $logs_dir)
    {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->logs_dir = $logs_dir;
    }
```

?

Comment: I tried it, nothing changed. But the Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager was underlined, it says "Undefined namespace Persistence".

Comment: ok put only `ObjectManager ` and let the IDE autocomplete the namespace

Comment: and they try also `EntityManagerInterface` as typehint

Comment: next thing I would say is to update vendors to the most recent possible version, I found some issues on internet for your problem, and eventually they said to update doctrine

Comment: also, unfortunately next thing is to consider not using FOSUserBundle, it's quite deprecated now

Comment: Yes I had cleared the cache. Okay so maybe I should update doctrine then? I'm using doctrine-bundle 2.2, doctrine-migrations-bundle 3.0.2 and orm 2.8.1. Which versions should I update and to which one?

Comment: the most recent possible, I think the bottleneck is the compatibility  with FOSUserBunde

Comment: I can't find the most recent versions, it seemed that my version are the highest. When I do composer update i get an error.

Comment: "composer update" does not update a vendor to the latest version in absolute, but to the latest version possible according to your composer.json

Comment: for example if in composer.json you have xxx:2.*, when you run "composer update", it won't go further then 2.* version, even if for example v3.1 is available

you should then use "composer require" to upgrade the vendor version, not "composer update"

Comment: I see, then what should I use? Since composer update doesn't upgrade and I don't know which version I need, I can't find it on the Internet

Comment: can you paste the composer.json?

Comment: I did an edit in my initial post to put the composer.json

Comment: it seems you are already using the latest versions
I'm sorry, I can't tell you any more things without looking at the code and spending a little time on it making some trials

Comment: if you really need, consider me for resolving this as freelancing activity. sorry for not being able to help you anymore before this

Comment: No problem I totally understand, thanks anyway

Comment: @Inmarelibero The error message is actually coming from FOSUserBundle's UserManager not the apps UserFactory.  Pretty sure the rest of the code was posted just as a bit of diversion.